# Get Object from memory using memory address

Tags: android, memory, mediarecorder

I want to know how to get an Object from memory, in my case a MediaRecorder. Here's my class:

Mymic class:

```
public class MyMic  {

    MediaRecorder recorder2;
    File file;
    private Context c;

    public MyMic(Context context){
        this.c=context;
        recorder2=  new MediaRecorder();
    }

    private void stopRecord() throws IOException {
        recorder2.stop();
        recorder2.reset();
        recorder2.release();
    }

    private void startRecord() {

        recorder2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder2.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder2.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
        try {
            recorder2.prepare();
            recorder2.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my Receiver Class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context c;
    private MyMic myMic;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.c=context;
        myMic = new MyMic(c);
        if(my condition = true){
        myMic.startRecord();
        }else

        myMic.stopRecord();
    }
}
```

So when I'm calling `startRecord()` it create a new `MediaRecorder` but when I instantiate my class a second time I can't retrieve my Object. Can I retrieve my `MediaRecorder` with his address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your constructor for MediaRecorder inside the constructor for the class you are making, instead of inside the startRecord() method like this:

```
public class MyMic  {

MediaRecorder recorder2;
File file;
private Context c;


public MyMic(Context context){
    this.c=context;
    recorder2=  new MediaRecorder();

}


private void stopRecord() throws IOException {
    recorder2.stop();
    recorder2.reset();
    recorder2.release();

}


private void startRecord() {

    recorder2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder2.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder2.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
    try {
        recorder2.prepare();
        recorder2.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



}
```

Also I can't figure out exactly what you are trying to do with the logic inside your Constructor, but you should probably not be doing it the way you are. You shouldn't make your class so that you have to make a new instance of it each time you want to start / stop recording.  The end goal should be an object that you instantiate once and keep a reference to so that you can call start / stop on it whenever you like.

Can you post the Activity (or other Android structure) that you are using this class from within? I can help you to tie the two together in a cleaner fashion if so.

Comment: I edit my post with the code of my `BroadcastReceiver`but i guess i have to retrieve my object from memory with his adresse.

Comment: take out the if statement in your constructor and remove the action parameter (though based on your BroadcastReceiver code it seems as though you weren't using the Constructor that you posted anyway, since you have no action parameter in your code. See my edit. Try it this way and see how it goes.

Comment: i did it but i'm getting two different object. because every time my Receiver is triggered it recall the onCreate so a new MyMic object is passed to stopRecord();

Comment: None of the code you've pasted has an onCreate() method... And stopRecord() doesn't get passed any parameters, parameters go inside the parenthesis. So I am not sure what you mean. I would suggest you do some brushing up on your java syntax before trying to create something this complex with Android.

Comment: I'm so sorry i had my mind elsewhere. I meant onReceive(). Everytime my `BroadcastReceiver`is triggered the `onReceive()` is called. All i want is `startRecord()`if the `BrodcastReceiver`receive an action, else if it receive another action `stopRecord()`.

Comment: I don't think it will work that way with a BroadcastReceiver. You should have a Service instead that will sit in the background that you can trigger to start the audio recording. Since BroadcastReceiver dies after onReceive() is complete you have no way to get the reference to your MyMic object the next time onReceive() is called.

Comment: But just one thing. After my `BroadcastReceiver`dies the `Object`recorder2 is still in memory so it record ... can i just get it from his address and `Initialize` a new `MediaRecorder`with it ?

Comment: I don't know if there is technically a way to do that. I have never come across one, and even if it were possible it is probably not the best idea to rely on a memory address like that.

Comment: I switch to a `Service`like you suggest, now it work great. thanks ! Can you just Edit your answer so I can put it as the right answer.